# pdo_mysql error suddenly appears on drupal based website?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7, web-hosting

My drupal based website was working fine till yesterday but suddenly from no where today an error appeared

```
Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY' in /.../includes/database/mysql/database.inc on line 43
```

I didn't even changed or updated anything since yesterday, it suddenly appears from no where, before that it was working fine

On line 43 of database.inc this was written

```
 PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => TRUE,
```

I googled and got some idea that this is some sort of PDO_MYSQL error, i have not much idea why this error suddenly arrived

Can anyone please help me out

**Additional information**

- Linux Shared Webhosting
- DRUPAL 7
- Apache version   2.2.20
- PHP version  5.2.17
- MySQL version 5.0.92-community-log
- cPanel Version   11.30.3 (build 5)

Comment: Maybe ask the hosting provider whether they changed anything in the configuration?

Comment: web hosting company replied me there is some problem with your script, i but didn't changed anything

Comment: Did your webhost deactivate PDO? Create a php file wich contains the code `<?php phpinfo();?>`, it will display all your php config. Check if PDO is mentionned or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to a lot of different sources the pdo_mysql extension must be missing from your PHP installation. Either add it in php.ini or ask your hosting provider to do it for you.

Links:

- [Fatal error in D7 HEAD while running 'drush
  update'](http://drupal.org/node/510912)
- [Drupal 7: PHP fatal error 'Undefined class constant MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY' when trying to install on MySQL database](http://drupal.org/node/1016622)
- [Fatal Error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY'](http://code.google.com/p/pdoext/issues/detail?id=1)

They all say the same thing...install the pdo_mysql extension. Sounds like your hosting provider has disabled it!

Comment: Thanks. I've checked pdo_mysql is missing, i'm asking my web host for it

Answer (score 1):

This can also be due to a permissions issue. Sometimes, given the use of SuPHP or other configurations in which the apache (or other server) user can't run a file, you'll get this sort of error and PDO_MYSQL: will already be installed and operational.

If you have root access to the box, try doing a

```
sudo php /path/to/your/php/script.php
```

or recursively chown the directory to the appropriate apache user (usually apache or www-data) or the user who's home directory your files are resting in (the case in most shared servers).

```
chown -R apache:apache /path/to/web/files
```

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same problem.  My site suddenly went down.
I started looking at installing php extension php_pdo_mysql.dll from cPanel PHP PEAR as suggested above, but this failed.
I started a live chat with my host (Justhost) and it tuned out they had upgraded their php version. They fixed it in 2 minues.